# El formulario winforms se queda detrás de todas las ventanas

Tags: c#, windows-forms, report

Resulta que cuando voy a imprimir un reporte y muestro el diálogo para imprimir y luego cierro el report viewer, el formulario principal se me queda detrás de todas las ventanas que están abiertas en ese momento. Tengo que minimizar todas las ventanas para acceder al formulario principal de la aplicación.

Les dejó mi código a la hora de imprimir el report viewer:

```
string report = "DALISF.rdlc";
            reportViewer1.LocalReport.ReportEmbeddedResource = report;
            reportViewer1.LocalReport.ReportPath = Path.Combine(@"..\FORMATOS\", report);
            ReportDataSource rds1 = new ReportDataSource("Familias", Agregar);
            reportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Clear();
            reportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(rds1);
            ///<summary>
            /// Vista de impresión de la página
            ///</summary>
            reportViewer1.SetDisplayMode(DisplayMode.PrintLayout);
            // Esta linea que tenemos abajo sirve para rellenar toda la página en donde se muestra el informe
            reportViewer1.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
            ///<summary>
            /// Todo el ancho de la página
            ///</summary>
            reportViewer1.ZoomMode = ZoomMode.PageWidth;




        //reportViewer1.PrintDialog();
        // Añadimos los parámetros que van a tener los reportes en cuestión (tenemos que ponerle los mismos nombres que tienen en el informe)
        mAnadirParametros("CodigoDesdeFamilia", DesdeCodigo);
        mAnadirParametros("CodigoHastaFamilia", HastaCodigo);
        mAnadirParametros("NombreDesdeFamilia", DesdeNombreFam);
        mAnadirParametros("NombreHastaFamilia", HastaNombreFam);
        mAnadirParametros("Infopie", "Para cualquier duda o consulta contacte con CTI Canarias. Tlf: 922 365 002 - info@cticanarias.com");
        reportViewer1.LocalReport.SetParameters(reportv); //Añadimos los parámetros al reporte.
        reportViewer1.RefreshReport(); // El informe se refresca cada vez que lo carga.
        reportViewer1.Messages = myMessageClass;
        reportViewer1.RenderingComplete += new RenderingCompleteEventHandler(RenderingCompleteEventHandler);

    }

    //-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
    //
    //-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
    private void RenderingCompleteEventHandler(object sender, RenderingCompleteEventArgs e)
    {
        (sender as ReportViewer).PrintDialog();
    }
```

El código en donde mando a mostrar el formulario que contiene el report viewer es el siguiente:

```
    private void eClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Creamos una instancia del formulario en el cúal tenemos el reportviewer 
        Form3 f3 = new Form3(DesdeCodigo,HastaCodigo,DesdeNombreFam,HastaNombreFam);
        Form1 f1 = new Form1(); //Instanciamos el formulario 1.

        try
        {
            if (sender is DataGridView ||
                sender is Label)
            {
                //...
            }
            else
            {
                if ((sender as Control).Name == varGen.sNombreBotonCancelar)
                {
                    //...

                }
                else
                {
                    if (sender != varGen.oControlAnterior)
                    {
                        if (varGen.oControlAnterior != null)
                        {
                            mPeticiones(varGen.oControlAnterior, Keys.Tab);
                            if (varGen.bControlConErrores == true)
                            {
                                return;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            switch ((sender as Control).Name)
            {
                //--------------------
                case "btImprimir":
                    f3.Show(); //Mostramos el formulario.
                    f3.CargarReporte(false); //Cargamos el reporte para imprimirlo.
                    eClick(btCancelar, null); // cerramos el formulario como si le hayamos dado un click al botón cancelar.
                    break; //rompemos el bucle
                //--------------------
                case "btVistaPrevia":
                    f3.Show(); //Mostramos el formulario
                    f3.CargarReporte(true); //Cargamos el reporte de Vista Previa
                    eClick(btCancelar, null); // cerramos el formulario como si le hayamos dado un click al botón cancelar.
                    break; //rompemos el bucle
                //---------------------
                case "btCancelar":
                    Close(); //Cerramos el formulario
                    break; //rompemos el bucle
                //---------------------
                default: //por defecto no hacemos nada.
                    //...
                    break; //por defecto rompemos el bucle
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ctiMetodos.mMensajeDeError(ex);
        }
    }
```

Gracias. Saludos

Comment: ¿Podrías agregar la línea donde mandas mostrar el formulario que contiene el report viewer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ya encontré el error en mi código y consecuentemente el problema de porque el formulario no se me abría directamente y se quedaba detrás de otras ventanas. A la hora de abrir el formulario yo lo hacía con el método **.Show()** y por lo tanto me dejaba ir a la ventana de atrás y poder cambiar los datos aquellos que yo había escrito anteriormente.

Pues ese método lo cambiamos por el método **.ShowDialog()**, que nos abre una ventana modal, es decir, nos abre el formulario pero no nos deja cambiar nada en el formulario anterior y por lo tanto cuando cerramos el formulario 3 el programa se comporta como queremos y se nos abre el formulario 3 en la pantalla principal en la que estamos.